# Python Import Error: No module named webpack_loader

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I've tried to look at similar questions but have really struggled to find a solution to this problem. I know that there's going to be some super smart software engineer that has a better idea than I do though!

I have a single page website I've built in react.js with django backend.

It works on my computer but won't work when I have tried to load it into a server (PythonAnywhere). Really fustrated as I was really looking forward to having it online.

The error I'm receiving is below :

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f67f8b4cb90>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

ImportError: No module named webpack_loader
```

I have had a look at making clear the encoding for the **init**.py code, I think it may relate to my settings.py static_root and webpack_loader settings which are below.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djreact/static/root'))

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djreact/static'),
]

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/local/',  # end with slash
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats-local.json'),
    }
}
```

My github repo with the complete files and etc is https://github.com/Hewlbern/ConsultingPage.git .

I followed the advice given below but now get this error. I think it's due to me not using a virtual environment but unsure. Fix one problem and another one turns up!

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/django-admin'
```

Thanks in advance - I'm a complete n00b but i'm learning as fast as I can!

Comment: Make sure that you installed `django-webpack-loader`

Comment: Have you installed your requirements.txt? https://github.com/Hewlbern/ConsultingPage/blob/master/requirements.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PythonAnywhere has a specific configuration screen for configuring a virtualenv.  You can find more info in the documentation:

- http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError
- http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/VirtualEnvForNewerDjango

Comment: My lawday I'm still trying to work this out. Keep getting the error that this port is in use, I feel like my WSG file is wrong but it shouldnt be!

Comment: You also don't need to run your project manually on any port. PythonAnywhere will take the app in your `wsgi.py` and automatically run it for you.

Answer (score 11):

It is because you have not already installed the module `django-webpack-loader`.

Just use:

```
pip install django-webpack-loader
```

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine, inside your project virtualenv do,

```
(venv) nix1947@shining:/myProject$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Use this requirements.txt file in your server and install

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Note: Make sure you to verify you have `django-webpack-loader` in your requirements.txt file

Comment: Brilliant stuff. I think this is the answer just trying now. Just as a side note, should I be using a virtual environment? I am not using one currently. What are the advantages of using one?

Comment: I'm getting this error now for some reason. Included in main post!

Comment: Having virtual environment separate your project libraries with system libraries, so your system won't get polluted with your project libraries, and other is you can use the same libraries having different versions in different project

Comment: How would I create a virtual environment now and move files into it?

Comment: Using virtualenv command such that `virtualenv venv `  virtual environment command can get from `sudo pip install virtualenv`

Comment: Is that it? Would I then need to move files into this folder?

Comment: Yes move all your files and install all necessary package, even django also

Comment: Is this likely why I am getting this error as above?

Comment: And install this as well `pip install django-webpack-loader` and I hope this will solve problem

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after moving my source files to another directory.

I fixed it by updating the virtual environment path on the virtual env `activate` file located at `._venv/bin/activate`:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV='path/to/._venv'
```